# How to swap values in two column simultaneously with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(sqn = c("FOO", "BAR"), start = c(1, 99), end = c(531, 
1), strand = c("+", "-")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

That looks like:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  sqn   start   end strand
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1 FOO       1   531 +     
2 BAR      99     1 -
```

What I want to do is to swap values in `start` and `end` column 
if `strand == "-"`. The desired result is this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  sqn   start   end strand
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1 FOO       1   531 +     
2 BAR       1    99 -
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8):

An option would be

```
df %>% 
  mutate(start1 = ifelse(strand == "-", end, start), 
         end = ifelse(strand =="-", start, end)) %>% 
  select(sqn, start = start1, end, strand)
```

---

Or an easier option is

```
i1 <- df$strand == "-"
df[i1, c("start", "end")] <- df[i1, c("end", "start")]
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, If you had many columns, is there an option for ```select``` to get all other columns automatically and then specify just ```start = start1```?

Comment: @RussThomas Yes, you can do `select(start = start1, everything())`

Comment: @RussThomas because you are renaming the column, more correct is `select(start = start1, everything(), -start1)`